# Object not filling correctly

Tags: modeling

I have this object that I'm trying to make. It should look similar to half of a sphere but it is not perfectly spherical. I've got the basic shape down but as it stands there aren't any faces.

[image: The object that I'm trying to fill]

I just want to fill in the outside so it's not empty, but when I select parts of the object and press <kbd>F</kbd> it gives weird results.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get rid of the duplicate vertices you have in your geometry. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to *Vertex Select* mode. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices and press <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance*. Notice that this removes 36 duplicate vertices.

Now as far as I know there is no direct easy way to fill in all faces because blender would not know which sets of vertices should form a face. But you can use the power of *Bridge Edge Loops*.

`1` Select the top most vertex and press <kbd>NumPad+</kbd> 2 or 3 times
`2` Press <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to *Edge Select* mode
`3` Continue pressing <kbd>NumPad+</kbd> until last vertical edges are selected
`4` Press <kbd>C</kbd> to switch to *Circle Selection* mode
`5` Then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> top most vertex area to unselect those edges and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
`6` Go to menu *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops* to fill most faces

[image]

This will not fill all faces, there's one more set of faces you have to manually fill. Just select those 2 edge loops as shown below and then go to menu *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*. Then select the top most edges and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in the remaining faces.

[image]

Comment: In the _Bridge Edge Loops_ options menu bottom left of viewport you can set _Connect Loops_ > _Closed Loop_ instead of _Open Loop_, then you don't have to fill the last gap manually. Also no need to switch between _Vertex Select_ and _Edge Select_. Don't even go into _Vertex Select_ at all, select all with A in _Edge Select_ mode, M to merge by distance, then in sideview in wireframe or x-ray mode hit B and deselect the bottom and top edges by dragging with middle mouse button. Then _Bridge Edge Loops_ with _Closed Loop_ and the main part is done. Select top edges, F and it's complete.

Comment: I know the answer is already accepted, but I would suggest you edit it a little bit because this could be done in a similar way but still quicker and easier.

Comment: hey thank u Gordon for the tip. more things to learn! sure, i'll edit it tomorrow :)